# How to convert big numbers into scientific notation

Tags: sed, text-formatting, numeric-data

I am working on a file where I have columns of very large values.

(like 40 digits : `646512354651316486246729519751795724672467596754627.06843`
and so on ...)

I would like to have those numbers in scientific notation but with only 3 or 4 numbers after the dot. Is there a way to use `sed` or something to do that on every number that appears in my file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to convert only specific column, `awk` helps

```
$ cat ip.txt
foo 64651235465131648624672951975 123
bar 3452356235235235 xyz
baz 234325236452352352345234532 ijkls

$ # change only second column
$ awk '{$2 = sprintf("%.3e", $2)} 1' ip.txt
foo 6.465e+28 123
bar 3.452e+15 xyz
baz 2.343e+26 ijkls
```

Answer (score 13):

Your shell might have a `printf` builtin you can use to format numbers.

```
$ type printf
printf is a shell builtin
$ printf "%.3e\n" 646512354651316486246729519751795724672467596754627.06843
6.465e+50
$ printf "%.4e\n" 646512354651316486246729519751795724672467596754627.06843
6.4651e+50
$ _
```

If not, there's often a dedicated `printf` binary, too.

```
$ which printf
/usr/bin/printf
$ _
```